# SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. i tried all result found on stackoverflow and githubs

Tags: php, phpmailer

im new in php im trying to use phpmailer to send email using gmail
here is the code i wrote

> ```
> $mail = new PHPMailer(true);       
> try {
>     $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;          
>     $mail->isSMTP();               
>     $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
>     $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                            
>     $mail->Username = 'sendermail@gmail.com';      
>     $mail->Password = '<some password>';                   
>     $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                         
>     $mail->Port = 587;                                  
>     $mail->setFrom('anadresse@gmail.com', 'GestionStock');
>     $mail->addAddress('anadresse@gmail.com', 'hamza');  
>     $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
>     $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
>     $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
>     $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
>
>     $mail->send();
>     echo 'Message has been sent';
> } catch (Exception $e) {
>     echo 'Message could not be sent.';
>     echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
> } ?>
> ```

i got as results SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

can someone tell me what im doing wrong !!

Comment: can you manually connect to `smtp.google.com` on port `587` ? could a firewall on your side prevent that ?

Comment: Well, something is obviously not right with the provided SMTP configuration then. BTW, I hope that is not your real password. Otherwise you should change it _immediately_! Try to change to `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';` and `$mail->Port = 465;`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet , how can i do that manually ??

Comment: @ Connum , i tried what u said and i got 2017-10-21 14:49:06                SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: I think you have to activate in the gmail account the option to use SMTP else, won't work. For instance [Gmail Webmail - Remote SMTP Server - Setup Guide](https://www.authsmtp.com/gmail/index.html) (with a google quick search)

Comment: under linux, `nc smtp.google.com 587`

Comment: You need to turn on access to less secure apps , by default is turn off , check this link https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: @JGEstevez  i already turned on less secure , and still not working

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet not working for me under windows

Comment: Try to send an email from outlook or thunderbird with the same smtp settings

Comment: And disable your firewall....

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet  it works on outlook  account  with same smtp settings

Comment: how can i use gmail instead of outlook !! please

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer your question. Go through the troubleshooting guide, do what it says, post your `SMTPDebug` output in your question. You don't necessarily need to turn on less secure apps, and it doesn't explain connection failure.

Comment: did you disable your firewall ? just in case there is an exception for outlook but not your php script.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet yees i did disable my firewall and unfortunately it didn't  work

Comment: If you are using older version of `PHP Mailer` then also it will throw this error. Download the new version from [GitHub](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases) and include the new version in your project.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem I had using Gmail and I solved it by downloading the cacert.pem certificate from the site https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html You should also write the php.ini file as follows: extension = php_openssl.dll openssl.cafile = C: \ xampp \ php \ extras \ ssl \ cacert.pem 
It must be activated in the GMail account in the label: Access and security of the option:
Allow less secure apps access option: ON

This solution is thanks to the matteobin user contribution of stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

i figured out that the problem not from code , its from the account gmail , idk exactly what is but i have different accounts , some works and other not  working , i tried creating new gmail account and enabling lesssecureapps but not worked 
it works only in a specific gmail with a disabled lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0):

The following code has worked for me.

```
                    require('./phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
                    require('./phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
                    $mail=new PHPMailer();
                    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                        'ssl' => array(
                        'verify_peer' => false,
                        'verify_peer_name' => false,
                        'allow_self_signed' => true
                        )
                        );

                    $mail->CharSet =  "utf-8";
                    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
                    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  
                    $mail->Port = 465; 
                    $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
                   
                    $mail->isSMTP();

                    $mail->Username="myemail@gmail.com";
                    $mail->Password="mypassword";

                    $mail->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com','Some text here');
                    $mail->addAddress($email);
                    $mail->addReplyTo('myemail@gmail.com');

                    $mail->isHTML(true);
                    $mail->Subject="Confirmation email";
                    $mail->Body="<h2 style='text-align='center';'>Confirmation email</h2></br>
                    <p>Your message has been received. One of our team members will contact you shortly.</br></br>Thank you for contacting us.</p>";

                    if(!$mail->send())
                    {
                        echo "Message could not be sent!";
                        echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        echo "Message sent successfully!";
                    }
```

I was having the same problem. I added the following code:

```
                        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                        'ssl' => array(
                        'verify_peer' => false,
                        'verify_peer_name' => false,
                        'allow_self_signed' => true
                        )
                        );
```

It is because, in the newer version, PHP has implemented stricter SSL behaviour which has caused this problem. Hope this solves your problem as well.